# Ansys Pedestrian-Induced Vibration on Bridge

Tags: civil-engineering, vibration, ansys, bridges, ansys-workbench

I have a concrete girder box bridge that is 40 m long and 4 meters wide, and I would like to simulate the response of the bridge using Ansys random vibration for pedestrian traffic. What are reasonable PSD Acceleration values to use (please justify) and where should I apply these random vibrations? You can assume there are 10 people uniformly distributed along the bridge.

Comment: So try inputting the effects of pedestrians re The Millennium Bridge (London Millennium Footbridge).

Comment: is this a school work assignment?

Comment: Your local bridge code should define any requirements for this.